# get twitter profile picture using claims oauth 2

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I've got a site setup to accept twitter and facebook external logins.

Is there a way to get the twitter profile picture using claims?

```
var twitter = new TwitterAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ConsumerKey = AuthenticationSettings.Twitter.ConsumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = AuthenticationSettings.Twitter.ConsumerSecret,
                AuthenticationType = Constants.ExternalProviders.Twitter,
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
                Provider = new TwitterAuthenticationProvider()
                {
                    OnAuthenticated = async ctx =>
                    {
                        //SOME CODE HERE TO GET PROFILE PHOTO
                    }
                }
            };
```

Otherwise, what;s the best way of getting the profile photo?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is not an easy way to do this, you need to use the Twitter Api.

[Look here, get-the-twitter-profile-image-using-the-asp-net-identity](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/get-the-twitter-profile-image-using-the-asp-net-identity)